# is there any way to use tags in Android?

Tags: android, tags

I think I haven't explained my question properly. I want to add a text area in the xml which enable the user to choose content of an email, in addition be able to use tags which can change the content of the email based on the email address it is sending the emails to.For example user be able to add Dear and when the email is received by for example by another person whos email address is james @ mail.com , the email be Dear james. technically before the device send the email goes and check the name of the user's whos email address is james @mail.com from the database and replace the tag  with James. Do I make any sense?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Define what you mean by "tag"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you can do this:

```
String body = "<h1> any html! </h1>";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"me@test.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email");
       chooser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(chooser);
```

That will create you an HTML email. The body tag can be whatever you want it to be (even user input).

Is that what you meant?

Comment: thanks @Blundell, I think I haven't explained my question properly. I have amended my question.